# acceptance of non-recursively enumerable language by the Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, recursively-enumerable

I'd like to know if there's a non-recursively computable language that can be accepted by the Turing machine.
From the following definition of the recursively enumerable language:
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoVYC.png]

and from the fact that recursively enumerable = Turing recognizable (from wiki) I think the answer is non-recursively enumerable language **cannot** be accepted by the Turing machine.

But I lack the formal proof of it. I tried to negate the definition of RE and got "There is an algorithm that enumerates the members of S" is "there is **no** algorithm that can enumerates the numbers of S". But I don't understand how the Turing machine will behave in the case it gets the non-reclusively computable language as an input?

Comment: Are you aware of any example of a language that is not recursively enumerable?  Is it recursively computable?  Why or why not? Why are you negating the definition of RE?  Turing machines don't take languages as input.

Comment: @D.W. I'd think about complement of Halting problem. It is not in RE neither it's computable as its indicator function is not computable. Am I right?

Comment: So have you answered your own question?

Comment: @D.W. not really, as I'm still not aware of the formal proof of the statement "there is no RE language that can be accepted by the Turing machine". Neither can I understand how turing machine behaves with non RE language